# Is there a way to force an approval on code changes before allowing the commit to actually occur in subversion

Tags: svn

We have some architectural code that needs to be evaluated for potential conflicts with other code before we allow the code to be committed. At the minimum I would like to be notified that a certain file has been modified so that I can go and look at the file myself. Is there any way to have subversion do this?

Right now the only model we have is the programmer has read-only access to those files, and they can make changes locally but not commit them. They then need to email the file to me I look at the file determine if the change is appropriate and then perform the commit myself. This is a terribly arduous process and there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do both:There is a package called `svnmailer`, that can be used to send emails on certain events. On the other hand, you can restrict write operations on the trunk, and force everybody to make changes on *feature branches*. Only reviewers have the privileges to reintegrate feature branches into the trunk. Note that the reintegration is very simple, and can't create conflicts by itself.